# Задержка загрузки таблицы стилей в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался. Во всех браузерах нормально. В Mozilla Firefox при загрузке страницы примерно на пол секунды показывает страницу без стилей, очень раздражает. Файл стилей прописан в head как положено. Как лечить?

Comment: видимо файл слишком весомый, страница сформировалась, вывелась, а только потом стили подошли. Попробуйте отделить основные стили визуального характера, от более глубоких внутренних

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Решил добавив всем элементам:

```
transition:none!important;
```

По [этой статье](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/)